# How does the R function interSpline actually works?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline

I'm using the R function `interSpline` to smooth out a curve of a line with 9 points (so that it doesn't look like it's just connecting the dots). Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
plot(NA, NA, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), xlab = "p", ylab = "q")
lines(predict(interpSpline(data.x, data.fit)))
points(data.x, data.y, pch = 0)
```

However I can't find what methodology is actually being applied in the `interSpline` function.

Comment: Which packages does the function come from? Have you tried tying the function name into R and pressing enter (no parentheses)? If it's an S4 method, the digging is a bit harder. In that case, I find it easier to browse github or clone the code locally and explore it using e.g. Rstudio.

Comment: If it's `splines`, then it's in base R (it was removed from CRAN some time ago). `splines:::interpSpline.default` could be helpful. To Roman's suggestion for github, I typically start with Winston Chang's https://github.com/wch/r-source mirror, then search for the function `interpSpline`, and on page 2 you'll find a reference to the function: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/splines/R/splineClasses.R#L122

Comment: it's from the `splines` R package

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but looking at the deeper code of the function isn't helping. I was wondering if there was any document of the function that explained the rationale behind it or something close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment: As you do not provide a reproducible example, I just started with `??interSpline` suggesting `splines::interpSpline`.

From the docs:

> An object that inherits from (S3) class spline. The object can be in
>   the B-spline representation, in which case it will be of class
>   nbSpline for natural B-spline, or in the piecewise polynomial
>   representation, in which case it will be of class npolySpline.

Thus, your question depends on the way you use it (it is class dependent). People could help further, if you provide a mminimal reproducible example.

(In general read [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R.)